# Human-readable time interval function for Elfeed

Tags: formatting, time-date, elfeed

Is there some built-in or third-party function I can use for the following?

The function

```el
(elfeed-entry-date entry)
```

returns the timestamp for an RSS feed entry, e.g. `1518282912.0`.

I would like to use this as

```el
(message "%s" (elfeed-entry-date entry))
```

but instead of `1518282912.0` the result should be

`2 hours ago` or `n days ago` or `x years ago` ...

What I tried: Did some googling, found a somewhat related SO question that deals with Clojure.

There's also a ruby method called `distance_of_time_in_words` but of course this question is about Elisp.

Comment: For those of us who are unfamiliar with elfeed and may not immediately recognize the time format `1518282912.0`, it may be helpful to let the readers know what that format is.  Once we know, we can all do Google searches such as:  **emacs convert elfeed absolute days to hours**, and so on.  Then, someone can write up a custom solution if it does not exist.  Alternatively, consider providing us with a link to the source code beginning line that defines `elfeed-entry-date`.

Comment: What @lawlist said. FWIW, relevant Emacs formatting functions include `seconds-to-string`, `format-seconds` and `format-time-string`. See the relevant sub-nodes of [`(elisp) System Interface`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/System-Interface.html). If you use Gnus there is also the function `gnus-user-date` in `lisp/gnus/gnus-sum.el` whose output can be customised via the alist `gnus-user-date-format-alist`.

Comment: (elfeed-entry-date entry) returns the same type as the emacs builtin (float-time)